# MySQL Multiple joins without combining to same row

Tags: mysql, join

I have five tables as follows, and the result set at the end I'd like to get out of a query, where each row is one id from one of the `c1`, `c2` or `c3` tables, along with their corresponding `a` and `b` id's.

The query I'm currently trying and the result set I'm currently getting is at the end.

**a**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

**b**

```
+----+------+
| id | a_id |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    2 |
+----+------+
```

**c1**

```
+-----+------+
| id  | b_id |
+-----+------+
| c11 |    1 |
| c12 |    2 |
+-----+------+
```

**c2**

```
+-----+------+
| id  | b_id |
+-----+------+
| c21 |    1 |
| c22 |    3 |
+-----+------+
```

**c3**

```
+-----+------+
| id  | b_id |
+-----+------+
| c31 |    2 |
| c32 |    3 |
+-----+------+
```

**desired query result**

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | b_id | c1_id | c2_id | c3_id |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | c11   |       |       |
|  1 |    2 | c12   |       |       |
|  1 |    1 |       | c21   |       |
|  2 |    3 |       | c22   |       |
|  1 |    2 |       |       | c31   |
|  2 |    3 |       |       | c32   |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**query**

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, c1.id, c2.id, c3.id
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN c1 ON c1.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c2 ON c2.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c3 ON c3.b_id = b.id
```

**actual result**

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | b_id | c1_id | c2_id | c3_id |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | c11   | c21   |       |
|  1 |    2 | c12   |       | c31   |
|  2 |    3 |       | c22   | c32   |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You probably need to do a run for each c. It seems right now you want to join and separate using the same conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try This one Hope it useful to you

```
 (
   SELECT a.id, b.id, c1.id as c1id, "" as c2id, "" as c3id
   FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
   INNER JOIN c1 ON c1.b_id = b.id
 ) 
 union 
 (
   SELECT a.id, b.id,"" as c1id, c2.id as c2id, "" as c3id
   FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
   INNER JOIN c2 ON c2.b_id = b.id
 ) 
 union 
 (
   SELECT a.id, b.id,"" as c1id,"" as c2id, c3.id as c3id
   FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
   INNER JOIN c3 ON c3.b_id = b.id
 )
```